# nest Angular component inside <SVG> container?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, svg

I want to nest an Angular component inside an SVG container. However, the CSS selector tag `<app-square>` turns red and won't allow it. It works fine if I change the `<svg>` tags to a `<div>` or another container, but I think that I need an SVG. Any tips for getting around this?

Here is my code:

```
<svg *ngFor="let row of boardArray">
    <app-square *ngFor="let sqare of row" [reciever] = "sqare"></app-square>
</svg>
```

I'm also passing data to the child objects, but I think that's unrelated. The CSS selector tags still show up red even with just:

```
<svg>
    <app-square ></app-square>
</svg>
```

I'm extremely new to HTML, CSS, and Angular. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

The reason that I think I need an SVG container is this. The HTML view template for the SquareComponent contains only an SVG `<rect>` element. It looks like this:

```
<svg>
    <rect [attr.x] = "reciever.x" [attr.y] = "reciever.y" width="100" height="100" fill = "brown"></rect>
</svg>
```

I want the parent component to display the squares in an 8x8 grid, with each square adjacent to the next (I'm trying to make a chess board). The Square Component's properties reciever.x and reciever.y hold the x and y coordinates of each square, but I'm under the impression that all the Square Components (displayed as svg `<rect>`s) need to be in a singular SVG container in order to position them exactly adjacent to one another.

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

Since we need to use components for a child of `svg` I am using the component with the attribute selector `[rectangle]` then using the `@HostBinding` to set the individual properties of the squares this will solve your issue!

The remaining of the workings is explained in the code below!

We need to use `@for` (same as *ngFor) to loop through identical length of rows and columns which I generate using `new Array(this.chessBoardSize).fill(null)`, then we can run two `@for` for the rows and columns and generate the rectangles by multiplying the unit with of the rectange by the index, to create the chessboard.

For the Colors we use the logic `value % 2 === 0` to identify if the row index is odd or even and then we use the same logic to determine if the column index is odd or even to finally generate the chessboard.

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: '[rectangle]',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: ``,
})
export class Rectangle {
  @Input() rowIndex = 0;
  @Input() columnIndex = 0;
  @Input() chessSquareSize = 0;
  @HostBinding('attr.x') get x() {
    return this.rowIndex * this.chessSquareSize;
  }
  @HostBinding('attr.y') get y() {
    return this.columnIndex * this.chessSquareSize;
  }
  @HostBinding('style.fill') get fill() {
    return this.getColorType(this.rowIndex, this.columnIndex) ? 'red' : 'black';
  }

  getColorType(rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) {
    return rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? columnIndex % 2 === 0 : columnIndex % 2 !== 0;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent, CommonModule, Rectangle],
  template: `
    <svg>
      @for(squareRow of rows; let rowIndex = $index;track rowIndex) {
        @for(square of columns; let columnIndex = $index;track columnIndex) {
          <rect [attr.x] = "rowIndex * chessSquareSize" [attr.y] = "columnIndex * chessSquareSize" width="10" height="10" [ngStyle]="{ fill : getColorType(rowIndex, columnIndex) ? 'red' : 'black'}"></rect>
        }
      }
    </svg>
    <!-- using child component -->
    <hr/>
    <svg>
      @for(squareRow of rows; let rowIndex = $index;track rowIndex) {
        @for(square of columns; let columnIndex = $index;track columnIndex) {
          <rect rectangle width="10" height="10" [rowIndex]="rowIndex" [columnIndex]="columnIndex" [chessSquareSize]="chessSquareSize"></rect>
        }
      }
    </svg>
  `,
})
export class App {
  chessBoardSize = 10;
  chessSquareSize = 10;

  get rows() {
    return new Array(this.chessBoardSize).fill(null);
  }

  get columns() {
    return new Array(this.chessBoardSize).fill(null);
  }

  getColorType(rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) {
    return rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? columnIndex % 2 === 0 : columnIndex % 2 !== 0;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-s14upp?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I have to use SVG rather than other elements because it allows me to create a graphics window where I can position each <rect> using coordinates. My problem is my implementation - I want each square to be its own component, which is just a <rect>, but all of the squares to be contained in an <SVG> container.

Answer (score 1):

Using a directive (Stolen the idea of Naren Murali)

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[square]',
  standalone:true,
})
export class SquareDirective implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input() rowIndex=0;
  @Input() columnIndex=0;
  @Input() chessSquareSize=10;
  constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('x',this.columnIndex*this.chessSquareSize)
    this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('y',this.rowIndex*this.chessSquareSize)
    this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('width',this.chessSquareSize)
    this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('height',this.chessSquareSize)
    this.el.nativeElement.style.fill=this.rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? 
                                     this.columnIndex % 2 === 0 ? 'red':'black':
                                     this.columnIndex % 2 === 0 ? 'black':'red'
  }
}

<svg>
  @for(squareRow of rows; let rowIndex = $index;track rowIndex) {
    @for(square of columns; let columnIndex = $index;track columnIndex) {
      <rect square [rowIndex]="rowIndex" 
                   [columnIndex]="columnIndex" 
                   [chessSquareSize]="chessSquareSize" >
      </rect>
    }
  }
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have a lot of work to do when doing drap-drop to move pieces around **within *one SVG***

Making the chessboard with 64 DIVs in a CSS Grid and the individual pieces with SVG will be easier HTML and you can use the native Drap-Drop API

Or use my existing Web Component:

```html
 <script src="https://chessmeister.github.io/elements.chessmeister.js"></script>

 <chessmeister-board 
       fen="rnbqkbnr/
            pppppppp/
            8/
            8/
            8/
            8/
            PPPPPPPP/
            RNBQKBNR" >
    </chessmeister-board>
```

Source: https://chessmeister.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

In the old days you could use `<svg:svg></svg:svg>` to let the compiler know it is indeed an SVG element. Try using that, see if it works ?

Otherwise, you can create SVG templates for your components instead of HTML ones. I think this would be the closest you can get to what you want to achieve.